# Cron Job PHP Script Fails but Script will run via CLI or through browser

Tags: php, linux, bash, cron

I have several php scripts I am trying to set up (recently moved to a new server) they will run from the command line and through the browser but only one will run through cron the other seems to have a permissions problem, if the file is set to 644 I get this message from cron:
/bin/sh: /home/xyz/public_html/scripts/update-script.php: Permission denied

If I set permissions to 777 I get this message:

/home/xyz/public_html/scripts/update-script.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory

/home/xyz/public_html/scripts/update-script.php: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"includes/clsDatabase-list.php"'

/home/xyz/public_html/scripts/update-script.php: line 2: ` require_once("includes/clsDatabase-list.php");'

yet the script runs from the command line and via browser AND i have another script that is almost identical to this one (calls for the same include on line 1, is located in exactly same folder) that will run through cron! So I know my paths and cron job that I setup in Cpanel are right. If I copy the working one in the command line, the copied version also fails to run via cron. Thanks!

Comment: show your script code

Comment: Not really necessary, the error contains all necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a shebang to your file to execute it directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
//...
```

Another option would be calling it like this in your cronjob:

```
* * * * * php /home/xyz/public_html/scripts/update-script.php
```

Of course you'd replace the `* * * * *` with the actual crontab data unless you want it to run every minute.

Comment: Shebang worked! Not sure why one script needs and other doesnt, also your second option is exactly how the script was called and doesnt works. Thank you very much